# Is there a way to dynamically change visible rows in ComboBox

Tags: java, dynamic, drop-down-menu, javafx, combobox

Consider the following MCVE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MCVE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ComboBox<String> box = new ComboBox<String>();
        box.setEditable(true);

        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        box.setItems(list);

        box.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            // Clear the list
            list.clear();
            int rows = 0;

            // Add a dummy item to the list for every character i newValue.
            for (int i = 0; i < newValue.length() && newValue.length() < 10; i++) {
                list.add(i+"");
                rows++;
            }

            // Does not work.
            box.setVisibleRowCount(rows);
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(box));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

When you add some characters to the `ComboBox`, the amount of items in the list increases. But the amount of visible rows in the dropdown does not change. For this to change, you need to hide and show the dropdown. The problem also occurs when the amount of items in the list decreases.

In my opinion, this should change dynamically.

This [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095352) seems to cover a similiar issue. Although in that case the problem persisted when the dropdown is shown after being hidden, which is not the case in my example.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094062/javafx-combobox-not-refreshing-the-number-of-visible-rows) raised a similar question, except the question was why `setVisibleRowCount()` does not work when you show the dropdown after being hidden. Mine is instead how to actually accomplish a dynamically changing row count while the dropdown is being shown. I've also tried the fixes presented in the above linked thread, both setting the cell size of the `ComboBox` list cell and setting a another visibleRowCount before setting it to you actual value to trigger an update. Neither seems to work.

A possible fix for this would be to just hide and show the drop down whenever the list size is changed, but this causes the drop down to flicker, which is annoying.

The list should probably keep some kind of maximum allowed visible rows, as it does with the default implementation.

Tested environment: Windows 8.1 Enterprise, Java 8u74.